# Regular Expression for "Begging with" AND total number of charaters

Tags: regex

I have a little requirement where I need to filter a number based on 2 criteria using #regex

1. starts with +92
2. containing 13 characters

input string +923456789123

I have tried an expression with OR operator like (^.{13}$)|(^+92) and it works, however I need to have AND rather then OR

Thankx

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
^\+92[0-9]{10}$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `\+` matches the character + literally
- `92` matches the characters 92 literally
- `[0-9]{10}` match a single character present in the list below
   Quantifier: `{10}` Exactly `10` times
   `0-9` a single character in the range between `0` and `9`
- `$` assert position at end of the string

Answer (score 0):

The regex is `^\+92.{10}$`:

- `^` Start of string
- `\+92` The first 3 characters (you need to escape the plus, since it has another meaning in regular expressions)
- `.{10}` Since we have already matched 3 characters, we need only match the remaining 10.
- `$` End of string.